NavigationView Scroll is not working only for last two Items
I have been trying to make my NavigationView scrollable to be able to view all items inside it. I am using menu items to populate my NavigationView. The NavigationView scroll is actually working but the scroll view shows the all items except the last two while scrolling. For Example In the NavigationView only last two items cropped from the menu item and user tried to scroll to see the remaining items the Scroll is not working. At the same time if the menu item more than 2 means the scroll is working but when user scroll to see the items all menu items shows and the scroll not working when it's reached last 2 items.
Here is my XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/sideMenuNavigationView"
        style="@style/side_menu_style"
        android:background="@color/violent_violet"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:menu="@menu/side_bar_menu">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menuRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            tools:listitem="@layout/side_menu_items" />
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


Style:
<style name="side_menu_style" parent="general_menu_style">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">end</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="headerLayout">@layout/side_bar_header</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

The Expected Behavior is the NavigationView scroll should work for all items. I mean user can see the all items that given in the side menu items layout
